# Invalid parameter key zone for CreateVolume

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a volume using pvc and keep getting the following error:

```
W0223 08:14:27.125940       1 controller.go:934] Retrying syncing claim "32886053-35bc-4a85-8e19-da61fb64f946", failure 24
E0223 08:14:27.125957       1 controller.go:957] error syncing claim "32886053-35bc-4a85-8e19-da61fb64f946": failed to provision volume with StorageClass "performance-aws-scratch-1": rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Invalid parameter key zone for CreateVolume
I0223 08:14:27.125970       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"PersistentVolumeClaim", Namespace:"aws-performance-ci-cd-pipeline", Name:"scratch0-0", UID:"32886053-35bc-4a85-8e19-da61fb64f946", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"596060227", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'ProvisioningFailed' failed to provision volume with StorageClass "performance-aws-scratch-1": 
rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Invalid parameter key zone for CreateVolume
```

here is my storage class yaml. I am on AWS cloud. zone seems to be correct to me.

```
(base) % kubectl get storageclass performance-aws-scratch-1 -o yaml
allowVolumeExpansion: false
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"allowVolumeExpansion":false,"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"performance-aws-scratch-1"},"parameters":{"csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype":"ext4","encrypted":"true","iopsPerGB":"1","type":"io1","zone":"us-east-1a"},"provisioner":"ebs.csi.aws.com","reclaimPolicy":"Delete","volumeBindingMode":"Immediate"}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-02-15T22:08:54Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:allowVolumeExpansion: {}
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:parameters:
        .: {}
        f:csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: {}
        f:encrypted: {}
        f:iopsPerGB: {}
        f:type: {}
        f:zone: {}
      f:provisioner: {}
      f:reclaimPolicy: {}
      f:volumeBindingMode: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-02-15T22:08:54Z"
  name: performance-aws-scratch-1
  resourceVersion: "591236324"
  uid: a65feb4f-db14-4826-a38a-3df655cab3ff
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: ext4
  encrypted: "true"
  iopsPerGB: "1"
  type: io1
  zone: us-east-1a
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Any pointers to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified an invalid key "zone" under "parameters". Try:

```
...
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: ext4
  type: io1
  iopsPerGB: "1"
  encrypted: "true"
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone
    values:
    - us-east-1a
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```